# SCPI - concatenated commands order

Tags: string

I have question about the SCPI rule that I cannot find answer for it.
Let's see those concatenated shorted DUMMY commands:

```
:HOME:COLOR RED;MATERIAL:HEIGHT 3 M
```

It's equal to:

```
:HOME:COLOR RED;:HOME:MATERIAL:HEIGHT 3 M
```

But what if I get the next string:

```
:HOME:COLOR RED;MATERIAL:HEIGHT 3 M;AREA 5 M2
```

Is it equivalent to:

```
:HOME:COLOR RED;:HOME:MATERIAL:HEIGHT 3 M;:HOME:AREA 5 M2
```

or to:

```
:HOME:COLOR RED;:HOME:MATERIAL:HEIGHT 3 M;:HOME:MATERIAL:AREA 5 M2
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! After a lot of searching and talking with many other programmers, I found in specification of SCPI that if commands are written in concatenated form (like in my question), the command after semicolon related to the PREVIOUS node!
So, if string is:

```
:HOME:COLOR RED;MATERIAL:HEIGHT 3 M;AREA 5 M2
```

It's shorted form of

```
:HOME:COLOR RED;:HOME:MATERIAL:HEIGHT 3 M;:HOME:MATERIAL:AREA 5 M2
```

Now it's clear for me!

Thanks a lot! :)